# How can I use Expression<T> in NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, irepository

I have read the very good blog post of Rob Conery [Crazy Talk: Reducing ORM Friction](http://blog.wekeroad.com/blog/crazy-talk-reducing-orm-friction/)
How can I generalize this interface so I can implement it with NHibernate?

```
using System;  
using System.Collections;  
using System.Linq;  
using System.Linq.Expressions;   


public interface IRepository<T>   
{  
     IQueryable<T> GetAll();  
     PagedList<T> GetPaged(int pageIndex, int pageSize);  
     IQueryable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression);  
     void Save(T item);  
     void Delete(T item);  
}
```

I want to use the `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` expression in NHibernate. Any clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at LINQ to NHibernate. Kyle Baley has a great [overview of it](http://codebetter.com/blogs/kyle.baley/archive/2008/04/07/trying-out-linq-for-nhibernate.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to walk the expression tree and build your Criteria.